# Tastypie "always_return_data" option changed response Status codes

Tags: django, rest, http, tastypie

I have a Tastypie API, I wanted to get the "id" of the created resource on POST request, so the only solution I found was "always_return_data" which returns the whole object.

```
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource
from tastypie.authorization import Authorization
from tastypie.authentication import SessionAuthentication

from myproject.core.models import MyModel


class MyResource(ModelResource):
    ...

    class Meta:
        queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'mymodel'
        allowed_methods = ['get', 'put', 'post']
        authentication = SessionAuthentication()
        authorization = Authorization()
        always_return_data = True  # Added later
```

And this works just fine. But In the Beginning I had written tests and had:

For POST: `self.assertHttpCreated(self.api_client.post('self.detail_url', format='json', data=data))`

And for PUT: `self.assertHttpAccepted(self.api_client.put(self.detail_url, format='json', data=new_data))`

Now after I had set `always_return_data = True` The old tests Fail, coz POST is returnin 200 instead of 201 and PUT is retuning 200 instead of [202/204]
Is there a solution other than replaceing `assertHttpCreated` and `assertHttpAccepted` with `assertHttpOK` Or if possible, is it possible to just return th "id" of the newly-created resource on POST request without setting `always_return_data = True`. Any suggestion is welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As Per the spec (http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.6), status code `200` seems to be appropriate.

For good practice, always use `list_allowed_methods` and `detail_allowed_methods` 
rather than `allowed_methods`. 
change the `allowed_methods = ['get', 'put', 'post']`, and add

```
list_allowed_methods = ['get', 'post']

detail_allowed_methods = ['get', 'put']
```

If a new resource is created, return `HttpCreated` (201 Created). If `Meta.always_return_data = True`, there will be a populated body of serialized data.

If an existing resource is modified and `Meta.always_return_data = False` (default), return `HttpNoContent` (204 No Content). If an existing resource is modified and `Meta.always_return_data = True`, return `HttpAccepted` (200 OK).

For the test case, along with `assertHttpOK`, you can add a another test case to verify the response data object and request data object that you send while put/post.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is useful. I know that 200 OK on PUT or POST is appropriate but I was trying to be more accurate if it was possible.